# I can not use relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a relationship many to many between News and Friends, where relationships are friends to News and news to Friends.
But when I try to select the Friends of friendship field through News in NSPredicate can not. I'm doing like this:

```
let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "ANY friends.friendship == %d " , 0)
```

this line was to return all the news where friendship is equal to 0 (and there are friendships equal to 0) but does not return anything, and when I do:

```
let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "ANY friends.friendship == nil")
```

oh yes the condition returns as true, my relationship is returning nil do not know why. If you have someone who can help I thank you.

Comment: what is data-type of friendship? I think it is an NSIneger type as per code. SO you can't compare Int to nil.

Comment: friendship is the Integer yes but I've tried to compare with other fields as well and does not function only works when I compare the nil oh yes brings results